# Validations is not working when I use select tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, select

Validations is not working **when I use select tag** in rails

**if i remove the validations everything works fine** .

but if i keep validations
following error happens

```
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #10):

 <div class="field">

 <%= f.label :Vehicle_Number %><br />  
 <%= f.select "vehicle_id",
 options_from_collection_for_select(@vehicledevice,"vehicle_id","vehicle_number"),
 :prompt  => "No vehicle"%>

 </div>
```

please solve the problem

error is at f.select "vehicle_id" complete line

Comment: what validation??? please provide the code where the error happens `(around line #10)`

Comment: error is at f.select "vehicle_id" complete line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is you have @vehicledevice declared in your new action and when you submit the form it takes you to the create action which in turns give you the validations error. Just call the same @vehicledevice in your create action in the else block of your respond_to and the problem will be solved.